# How do I execute typescript watch and running server at the same time?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, command, package.json

I was developing my project in nodejs. I found if I need to code and test api, I will run two console, one is to execute typescript watch, another is to execute server.

I think it's so troublesome. I find other developers on github have written scripts in `package.json`. It's easy to call any commands. It attracts how to write the scripts and simply my development workflow.

In short, the comand of typescript watch is `tsc -w` and the comand of running server is `node app.js`. My idea is merge the commands as `tsc -w & node app.js` but I can't work the two commands at the same time. How do I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> My idea is merge the commands as tsc -w & node app.js but I can't work the two commands at the same time. How do I do

You have a few options. Simplest is to use `ts-node-dev` : https://github.com/whitecolor/ts-node-dev

Comment: Per the readme in the repo you linked (https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#watching-and-restarting):

```...watching files and code reloads are out of scope for the project. If you want to restart the ts-node process on file change, existing node.js tools such as nodemon, onchange and node-dev work.```

Comment: The readme used to mention how to setup `nodemon` explicitly. Now its just a link. Anyways I've moved to `ts-node-dev` anyways : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hi-ShZ5ShkE

Answer (score 17):

## Option 1

### Step 1

install `concurrently`, use `npm`, `pnpm` or `yarn`

```
pnpm i concurrently -D
```

### Step 2

create a script with this command

```json
"scripts": {
    "run": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon dist/app.js\"",
}
```

## Option 2

without install anything (mac or Linux)

```json
"scripts": {
    "run": "tsc -w & nodemon dist/app.js",
}
```

**Note: Run `tsc` first so that your directory `dist` has something at the time of running nodemon.**

And with that you will have **running your Typescript application**

Comment: In case of problems involving interactive cli applications (prompts with inquirer), include the `-r`/`--raw` flag in order to output in the raw mode (disables prettifying and concurrently coloring)

Answer (score 8):

Another option can be to use nodemon:

`tsc -w & nodemon app.js`

Since Typescript 3.4 the compilation is faster because you can use the `incremental` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html) and they keep improving (including [interesting changes for large projects in 3.8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/#assume-direct-dependencies)).

Update:

I also moved to use [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently) as [HerberthObregon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4168512/herberthobregon) says **[in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261813/how-do-i-execute-typescript-watch-and-running-server-at-the-same-time/59078526#59078526)**

Comment: How come it got  that many upvotes and doesn't work? Later command never run.

Comment: what issue are you facing @SujeetAgrahari? this works fine for me

Comment: @AviMehenwal `tsc -w` compiles and stays in watch mode, the other part `nodemon app.js` doesn't run

Comment: sorry this doesn't work, the second command never runs

Comment: It works on windows but not on linux, a couple days ago I move from windows to linux and suddenly the nodemon command ran but quickly being clean out its output by typescript command,.I don't know why, I choose to bear with it, run typescript watch on terminal and use nodemon for another one.

Answer (score 7):

TLDR, If you like [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) this is a straight forward way to get file watch, compilation and execution:

```
nodemon --ext ts --exec 'tsc && node dist/index.js'
```

Optionally replace tsc with babel for faster compilation.

Here is a more complete example, in package.json (with source maps):

```
"scripts": {
  "develop": "nodemon --ext ts --exec 'yarn build --incremental && yarn serve'",
  "build": "tsc",
  "serve": "node --require source-map-support/register dist/index.js",
  ...
},
```

Install [source-map-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support) as a dependency if you want, ahem... source map support! Otherwise, remove `--require source-map-support/register` from the `serve` script above.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice find. Doesn't auto-reload the browsers though. Looks like it's the only working solution atm.

Comment: It's definitely better to use incremental compilation or watch flags of the technologies in the project. It's super painful to recompile the entire project on each and every change.

Answer (score 3):

**As of 2023 [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx) seems to be the best options.**

If you're using it in an npm project, install it as a development dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev tsx
```

And add script to package.json like below

```
"scripts": {
    "compile": "tsx watch --clear-screen=false ./src/index.ts",
    "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js"
 },
```

Answer (score 3):

### Simplest modern method

`tsc --watch & node --watch dist/index.js`

There is a `--watch` flag starting from Node.js v18.
See [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/cli.html#--watch).

As of May 2023 it's marked as *experimental*, however I haven't faced any issues.

Please, note, that it doesn't support tsconfig 'paths' resolution, prefer [tsx](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx) or [ts-node-dev](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev) (looks unmaintained, unfortunately) if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Building on herberthObregon's answer

### Step 1: Install packages

```
npm install concurrently typescript nodemon --save-dev
```

### Step 2: Create these scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "tsc",
   "build:watch": "tsc -w",
   "dev": "npm run build && concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve:watch\"",
   "serve": "node dist/index.js",
   "serve:watch": "nodemon dist/index.js"
},
```

- build runs a standard typescript build
- build:watch runs typescript build in watch mode
- serve serves up your node project (assuming your tsconfig outputs to dest/index/js)
- serve:watch uses nodemon to restart the node server whenever the js output changes
- dev puts them all together

Comment: Just note that depending on the tools used, restarting node on each change may be suboptimal. React and Next, for example, have dev modes where they take care of the node server for you. While dev builds don't always duplicate *everything* of a full optimized server build, they can save a lot of time if you're making a lot of changes. Then you can run the full production-optimized build once at the end to validate nothing has broken.

Answer (score 1):

Just going to throw my hat in here, here's a solution using `ts-node-dev` and `concurrently`, similar to the one provided by @HerberthObregon but using `ts-node-dev` instead of `nodemon`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run dev\"",
    "dev": "tsnd --respawn src/main.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.release.json",
    "build:watch": "tsc -w -p tsconfig.release.json"
}
```

Bonus: If you need help with your figuring out `tsc`and your `tsconfig.json`, I use the sensible defaults from this [node typescript starter](https://github.com/jsynowiec/node-typescript-boilerplate).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works for me

**1. Install ts-node and nodemon as dev dependencies**

**2. Create a script** :  `"dev" : "nodemon app.ts"`