# Typescript npm script with compilation and nodemon issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nodemon, tsc

I have been following several SO links on how to run both tsc -w and nodemon app.js in a single command.

Link which i followed:
[How do I execute typescript watch and running server at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261813/how-do-i-execute-typescript-watch-and-running-server-at-the-same-time)

I was working on a project in node.js with typescript. Each time when there is change in ts code, I want to compile using tsc -w and then execute running server with nodemon app.js file. The problem is I tried with both commands, but still it is not running the second command. I have no idea why it is not working.

Commands I used inside package.json scripts

`"dev1": "tsc -w && nodemon ./.build/src/app.js"`,

`"dev2": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon ./.build/src/app.js\""`

Ran npm run dev1

Ran npm run dev2

Currently only the first command is running and I am not able to see the logs which will come when nodemon runs. Terminal is showing only below log:

`Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes`

[Note: both commands are running perfectly when i tried to run one after another]

Versions using (bit older)

typescript: 3.0.1

nodemon: 2.0.7

ts-node: 5.0.1

Any help would be really appreciated. I dont want to use any extra package like ts-node-dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are still struggling to get a solution finally I came across a solution from [Is there a way to use npm scripts to run tsc -watch && nodemon --watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276862/is-there-a-way-to-use-npm-scripts-to-run-tsc-watch-nodemon-watch)

Add the below script to package.json

```
"dev": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -e ts  --exec \"tsc && node ./.build/src/index.js\""
```

Once you made the code changes simply run the dev script with npm run dev which starts nodemon and makes it watch .ts files (using -e flag). Then, every time a .ts file changes nodemon will exec the task which basically compiles and runs the node app.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check (and double check)

- make sure you have installed the `typescript` package (and not the `tsc` package). do `npm uninstall tsc; npm i -D typescript`
- make sure you run the `tsc` command correctly, e.g. `tsc -w app.ts` (or create a detailed `tsconfig.json` if you have a whole source directory
- make sure you are giving the right path to the nodemon

This is a working script to get started with:

```sh
mkdir my-ts-project
cd my-ts-project
npm init -y
npm i -D concurrently typescript nodemon
vim app.ts
npx concurrently "npx tsc -w app.ts" "nodemon app.js"
```

and then you can change `app.ts` and see changes reflected.

---

Tip: I suggest using `ts-node-dev` instead of `nodemon` and use `tsc` only for production build. It is easier.